# Python 3 - can't delete a space in a string using replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running into a weird problem.  I load all usernames from the database, then I replace any space found in the username with nothing, so it gets remove.  but it's not working, the space stays there! Here is my code

```
users = User.query.all()
for u in users:
  username = u.username
  print (username)
  new_username = username.replace(" ","")
  print (new_username)
```

as an exemple, the first print returns:
"MavNandi 7"
and the second return the same
"MavNandi 7"

The space stays there.  I am baffled.  Any clue?

Comment: What is the actual value? What does `print(ascii(new_username))` produce? Most likely it is not a regular space, it is probably a non-breaking space.

Comment: try `username.strip()`.

Comment: @Shreevardhan `strip` only looks at leading and trailing whitespace; and even if that worked here, it would not solve the problem of understanding what’s going on.

Comment: Thanks for the print(ascii(  tip, it indeed showed it was not a regular space.  MavNandi\xa07

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost certainly have a string with a space variant in it, not the bog-standard [U+0020 SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+0020) but more likely [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+00a0). The two characters look exactly the same when printed:

```
>>> 'MavNandi\xa07'
'MavNandi\xa07'
>>> print('MavNandi\xa07')
MavNandi 7
```

There may be others; the Unicode stardard defines [17 space separators](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Zs) for example, many of these look like a regular space (with varying width).

As you can see the interpreter, when echoing the value uses the `\xa0` escape sequence to differentiate the two. You can produce the same output by using the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) when printing:

```
>>> print(repr('MavNandi\xa07'))
'MavNandi\xa07'
```

There is also a [`ascii()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii), this works just like `repr()` but replaces any character outside the ASCII range with an escape sequence, making it perhaps easier to see combining characters and distinguish between Unicode glyphs that would otherwise look alike.

You could use a regular expression to replace all whitespace characters, including no-break spaces, tabs, newlines and anything else the Unicode standard designates as whitespace:

```
import re

username = re.sub('\s+', '', username)
```

The `\s` character class matches any such whitespace character, the `+` matches 1 or more such character when replacing; the second argument replaces all such matches with the empty string.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\s+', '', 'MavNandi\xa07')
'MavNandi7'
```

Comment: Additionally, you could try using the python debugger to step through you application and print the value of each variable to see if it is indeed a "normal space" you're trying to delete.

Here's a [link](http://web.stanford.edu/class/physics91si/2013/handouts/Pdb_Commands.pdf) if you're interested.

Comment: That was it, printing the ascii value indeed showed MavNandi\xa07.  The regular expression solved the problem .  Thanks! :)  Learned something new today, there are different type of spaces... who knew!